# Is there a way to append a dumped dictionary or a dumped object in general using python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, dump

I have a dictionary let say:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3 }
```

All I want to do is to dump this dictionary into a file and then append
it with data produced by my program little by little. I don't want to have
the dictionary data in memory during the running of the program. By the end I
want to be able to load this file into a python structure from another
program.

Is there a solution to do this using `pickle` or `json` or another python
module? I know that you can't append to a dumped object in a pickle-file.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
d = pickle.load(open(fileName, 'rb'))
d.update(dictWithNewValues)
pickle.dump(d, open(fileName, 'wb'))
```

as described [here](http://www.python-forum.org/pythonforum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20779). But I want to do it progressively.. I understand that this may be difficult to do that way because dictionary has unique keys, so to be append it the current keys should be known to avoid conflicts (entries with same keys..).

So, is there a way to do it in a `list` or another python object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the keys of your dictionary are all strings, the simplest option I see is Python's [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) module.  A shelve behaves like a persistent dictionary, and any key can be updated.

Another option is the [`anydbm`](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html) module, which also requires all *values* to be strings.

Comment: It seems very close to what I want. But is it better in terms of memory usage than a simple dump at the end? I mean is it better to use the shelve or to have all the data in memory and then at the end to dump them all in a file? What I need is to reduce as much as possible the memory usage of this structure! Is there any equivalent for a python list?

Comment: @ThanasisPetsas: I'm assuming it is memory-efficient, though the documentation is not very clear on this point.

Comment: ok thank you very much Sven! It is very easy to use as it preserves the syntax of a simple dictionary object in python!